# Can I make a decision using a Bayes factor?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayes, bayes-factors

Bayes factors denote how well a certain model is supported. Say that I am running a controlled experiment and I have two models: the null model and the alternative model.

If I have a high Bayes factor, could I argue that the treatment is effective and propose making the change?

Comment: Could you go into more details? What exactly is your decision-making scenario? What two models do you have? What is unclear about using Bayes factors for you?

Comment: Whether or not to manufacture a new medication is the decision scenario. We want to determine whether this medication was actually effective.

Comment: Now, we have the Null Model (The drug was ineffective) and the Alternative Model (The drug was effective)

Comment: What exactly are your models? Could you edit and describe them in greater detail? What is your null model?

Comment: The Null model measures some physiological metric on paitents without the treatment

Comment: What do you mean by the model "measuring" something?

Comment: In Bayesian settings, one could argue that your prior skew the results in favor of one model. Consider using non informative prior and having large sample size

Comment: Okay, say that the prior isn't subjective.

Comment: Well, basically yes

Comment: Note: Bayes Factors can be alarmingly sensitive to the details of uninformative priors (and undefined for those that are improper). However, the sketched drug testing scenario also invites a simpler inference problem set within a single model that has a parameter representing the effect of drug treatment. That way you'll get a credible interval for the effect size as a bonus.

Comment: thank you conjugate prior (nice name). What would you recommend I make my decision on then?

Comment: Couldn't I just take the one with the highest MAP posterior?

Comment: I don't understand why somebody voted to close this as unclear. I think it's perfectly clear and the answer is basically **Yes,** but of course with some caveats as e.g. pointed out by @conjugateprior (+1). However, the first sentence of your question ("Bayes factors denote how well a certain model is supported") is wrong: Bayes factors are for comparing *two* models.

Comment: What is an appropriate way to determine whether I should employ this treatment?

Comment: Good judgement?

Comment: So - we just visualize and determine what I should do? Isn't there an entire fiedl called Bayesian Estimators?

Comment: No, there are no 'Bayesian estimators' or even, strictly speaking 'Bayesian estimation' (though there are estimators that can have a Bayesian motivation). There is, on the other hand, Bayesian inference. But what you get from *that* is not an estimator, or even an estimate, but a joint distribution for all unknown quantities that are mentioned in a model (a.k.a the posterior) conditioned on the data.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Bayesian decision theory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an excellent and deep question.

While traditional textbooks (like [mine](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983)) tend to promote Bayes factors as equivalent to posterior probabilities of the null and alternative hypotheses or of two models under comparison, which is formally correct as detailed in the following extract from my [Bayesian Choice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983), I now tend to think that the Bayes factor *per se* should *not* be used for decision-making but rather as a measure of relative evidence of one model versus the other. For instance, using $\mathfrak{B}^\pi_{01}(x)=1$ as the dividing line between null and alternative (or between model a and model b) does not strike me as a natural choice. Furthermore, I do not think the 0-1 loss advocated by Neyman and Pearson and later adopted by almost everyone is making much sense and brings any support to the decisional interpretation of the Bayes factor.

My current perspective on the Bayes factor is more in a prior or posterior predictive mode where the behaviour of $\mathfrak{B}^\pi_{01}(x)$ is assessed under both models, in order to calibrate the observed value $\mathfrak{B}^\pi_{01}(x)$ against both prior or posterior distributions of $\mathfrak{B}^\pi_{01}(x)$. This gets us away from the decisional perspective.

***[From [The Bayesian Choice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983), 2007, Section 5.2.2, page 227]***

> From a decision-theoretic point of view the *Bayes
>   factor* is only a one-to-one transform of
>   the posterior probability, but this notion came out to be considered
>   on its own ground in Bayesian testing.
>
> The *Bayes factor* is the ratio of the posterior probabilities of the
>   null and the alternative hypothesis over the ratio of the prior
>   probabilities of the null and the alternative hypothesis, i.e., $$
>  \mathfrak{B}^\pi_{01}(x) = {\mathbb{P}(\theta \in \Theta_ 0\mid x)
>  \over \mathbb{P}(\theta \in \Theta_1\mid x)} \bigg/  {\pi(\theta \in
>  \Theta_ 0) \over \pi(\theta \in \Theta_ 1)}. $$
>
> This ratio evaluates the modification of the odds of $\Theta_0$ against $\Theta_1$ due to the observation(s) and can naturally be compared to $1$, although an exact comparison scale can only be based upon a loss function.
>
> The Bayes factor is, from a Bayesian decision-theoretic point of view,
>   completely equivalent to the posterior probability of the null hypothesis as $H_0$ is accepted when
>   $$
> B^\pi_{01} (x) \ge {a_1\over a_0} \big/ {\rho_0 \over \rho_1}
>                 = {a_1\rho_1 \over a_0\rho_0},
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> \rho_0 &= \pi(\theta\in\Theta_0) \quad \hbox{ and } \nonumber\\
> \rho_1 &= \pi(\theta\in\Theta_1)\\
> &=1-\rho_0.
> \end{align*}
> $$

and where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are the penalties for *wrongly* selecting the alternative and null hypotheses or the models $\mathfrak{M}_0$ and $\mathfrak{M}_1$. respectively, in Neyman-Pearson formulation:
$$
\mathfrak{L}(\theta, \varphi) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $\varphi=\mathbb{I}_{\Theta_0}(\theta)$,} \cr
           a_0 &\text{if  $\theta\in\Theta_0$ and $\varphi=0$,} \cr
           a_1 &\text{if  $\theta\not\in\Theta_0$ and $\varphi=1$,}\cr\end{cases}
$$

Comment: (+1) Maybe you should add that $a_0$ and $a_1$ are the penalties associated to errors when the null is true or false.

Comment: Amazing answer Xi'an. Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it.

Comment: +1. I formatted the quote from your textbook as a quote -- apologies if you did not want to have it like that for some reason (feel free to revert my edit). I also removed the words "Panayiota Touloupou" that somehow got into the definition during the last revision.