# Model distribution in survival analysis

Tags: self-study, survival

I'm trying to fit a parametric survival model, Exponential, Weibull, Log-normal, Log-logistic. Now I need to use the residuals and hypothesis test to choice the best model for the data. My doubt is:

How I can use the residuals (Cox Snell, Martingal and Deviance) to choice the right model?

What more I can use to check the model fit (AIC, BIC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that AIC or BIC are the most commonly used. In cases in which your models are nested, you can use the log-likelihood ratio test or if you go Bayesian, you can use Bayes factors (BF). For details on BF see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203984/can-i-make-a-decision-using-a-bayes-factor?rq=1).